# How to use geom_rect (R ggplot) to plot bars with both negative and positive values on x-axis (xmin and xmax) with variable bar widths?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom

I am trying to make a  ggplot that shows a difference in biomass (called Migrant Biomass) on the x-axis and depths (as a continuous variable) on the y-axis. I also want the bars and space between labels on the y-axis to be indicative of the actual depth of the layer sampled (there are 9 with width ranges from 50 to 250 m).

I originally tried a ggplot bar graph using geom_bar, but then I am forced to plot the y-value (depth) as a categorical value. It seems like it is not possible to plot two continuous variables (biomass and depth) as a geom_bar plot. [geom_bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYBiE.png)

So, I am now using geom_rect to make my bars, which allows me to specify the xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax for each bar. This works great for showing depth as a continuous variable and specifying the width (ymin and ymax) of each bar, but I cannot figure out how to plot bars with a negative x-value (xmin) and xmax=0.

Would appreciate any help or other ideas of how to go about making a plot with positive and negative bars like this?  [Example of a plot I am trying to make with positive and negative bars, indicative of depth sampled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98NYE.png)

This is the code that I was trying:

Note: xmin=WW_x_min is 0 for all biomass differences that are positive. It is a negative weight value for all differences that are negative. xmax= WW_x_max is a positive weight value for all biomass differences that are positive. It is 0 for all biomass differences that are negative.

```
ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Wet Weight (mg m-3)", limits=c(-600, 300)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Depth (m)", trans = "reverse", 
                     breaks = c(0,50,100,300,500,700,800,1000,1250,1500), 
                     labels = c("0","50","100","300","500","700","800","1000","1250","1500")) + 
  geom_rect(data=DG5B_DG5C_SFComb_Wide_Simple, 
            mapping=aes(xmin= WW_x_min, xmax= WW_x_max, ymin=Depth_max, ymax=Depth_min), 
            fill="skyblue", color="black", alpha=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~Cruise+Site)+ labs(title="Migrant Biomass") + 
  theme_bw()+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(text=element_text(size=16), #change font size of all text 
        axis.text=element_text(size=16), #change font size of axis 
        text axis.title=element_text(size=16), #change font size of axis titles 
        plot.title=element_text(size=30), #change font size of plot title 
        legend.text=element_text(size=16), #change font size of legend text 
        legend.title=element_text(size=16)) + #change font size of legend title 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16)) #change front size of facet wrap text
```

but I get this error:

> Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Welcome to SO! As we don't have access to your data we can't neither run your code nor reproduce your issue. As is your code looks fine. Hence I can only guess that the issue is related to your data. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data, e.g. to share a snippet of the data run `dput(head(DG5B_DG5C_SFComb_Wide_Simple, 10))` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code which mostly replicates the [linked example plot in your question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98NYE.png), providing an example of plotting positive and negative bars of varying widths.  The key difference with this approach is using 2 facets to get the positive and negative parts of the plot looking nice (particularly when the scales are dramatically different).  The code in your question already has a facet on `~Cruise+Site`, so some changes to the code below may be needed to accomodate this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

df <- data.frame(
  side = c(rep(-1, 6), rep(1, 6)),
  strip = c(rep("Abundance~(fish~10^{-6}~m^{-3})", 6),
            rep('Biomass~(kg~ww~10^{-6}~m^{-3})', 6)),
  value = c(-2338, -2182, -1042, -1595, -770, -2219,
            5.51, 4.77, 5.44, 6.30, 1.84, 8.98),
  depth = c(0, 200, 750, 1500, 2300, 3300,
            0, 200, 750, 1500, 2300, 3300),
  depth_end = c(200, 750, 1500, 2300, 3000, 3500,
                200, 750, 1500, 2300, 3000, 3500)
)

scales <- list(
  `-1` = scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-3300, 0),
                            breaks = c(-3000, -2000, -1000), 
                            labels = c('3000', '2000', '1000'),
                            expand = c(0, 0), 
                            position = "top"),
  `1` = scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 12),
                           breaks = 1:10,
                           expand = c(0, 0), position = "top"))

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 0, xmax = value,
                          ymin = depth, ymax = depth_end,
                          fill = factor(side))) +
  geom_text(mapping = aes(x = value + ifelse(side == 1, 0.1, -50), 
                          y = (depth + depth_end)/2, 
                          hjust = 1 - (side > 0),
                          label = paste0('(', abs(value), ')'))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linewidth = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 200, 750, 1500, 2300, 3000, 3500),
                     labels = c('0', '200', '750', '1500', '2300', '3000', ''),
                     expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0), add = c(0, 100)),
                     trans = 'reverse') +
  facet_wrap(strip ~ ., scales = "free_x",
             labeller = label_parsed) +
  labs(y = 'Depth (m)', tag = 'Near bottom') +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = scales
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'grey')) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y= element_line(colour = "#AAAAAA", linewidth = 1,
                                         linetype = "dashed"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        plot.tag = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 0, face = 'bold'),
        plot.tag.position = c(0, 0),
        axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.x = unit(10, 'pt'),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none',
        text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image: Generated plot]